# CouchDB on windows says No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, couchdb

I am trying to use [`CouchDB`](https://github.com/kleingy/angular-simplecouch) as a back-end for my application. I tried to install couchDB on my windows OS machine. It works fine.

When i tried to run this [`example`](http://jsfiddle.net/WarwickGrigg/dCCQF/) after creating the db on "Projects",  the console displays an error.

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.
```

I tried to do fix it by this suggestion, [`how to add cors in couchDB`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20897033/how-to-add-cors-in-couchdb-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present), but i don't find **[cors]** section

I manually created [cors] section, that too did not work.

**UPDATE:**
I am using the latest version 1.6.1

Comment: create a cors section then?

Comment: @KimStebel i did that, did not work

Comment: what exactly did you do?

Comment: @KimStebel I went to this folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\CouchDB\etc\couchdb and opened local.ini and added the [cors] section

Comment: Dump Q, but what "environments" are involved? Are you actually trying to run the fiddle from JS-Fiddle against your machine?

Comment: i got it fixed , actually i was missing the ; before the cors section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to enable CORS on COUCHDB administration side and allow all sites